# word Transliteration in react-native/android

Tags: android, react-native

I have been trying to use Google Transliterate API using the RESTful approach

So, I came across this URL format: [http://www.google.com/transliterate/indic?tlqt=1&langpair=en|hi&text=bharat%2Cindia&tl_app=3](http://www.google.com/transliterate/indic?tlqt=1&langpair=en%7Chi&text=bharat%2Cindia&tl_app=3) which returns the JSON in the format:

```
[
{
"ew" : "bharat",
"hws" : [
"भारत","भरत","भरात","भारात","बहरत",
]
},
{
"ew" : "india",
"hws" : [
"इंडिया","इन्डिया","इण्डिया","ईन्डिया","इनडिया",
]
},
]
```

My question is that, how can i use this in android or react-native as API FORMAT